# wp_schedule_event for custom $recurrance parameter

Tags: php, wordpress, scheduler

I have a question in `wp_schedule_event` on its 2nd parameter that declares time to trigger the hook function. based on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event it has three valid value: `'hourly'`,`'twicedaily`', and `'daily'`.

What if I want it to run every 48hours? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom schedule interval.

eg; Add this to your functions.php or some other relevant location:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'gadss_add_twodays_cron_schedule' );
function gadss_add_twodays_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['twodays'] = array(
        'interval' => 172800, // 2 days in seconds
        'display'  => __( 'Once every two days' ),
    );

    return $schedules; 
}
```